# Regex html tags

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to figure out the regex for the following:

```
String</td><td>[number 0-100]%</td><td>[number 0-100]%</td><td>String</td><td>String</td>
```

Also, some of these td tags may have style attributes at some point.
I tried this:

```
String<.*>
```

and that returned

```
String</td>
```

but trying

```
String<.*><.*>
```

returned nothing.  Why is this?

Comment: what language are you using for the regex? java?

Comment: PHP, but that shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: It does, because some programming languages use different regular expression syntaxes.

Comment: README_FIRST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't be trying to use a regex to parse HTML, because that way [lies madness](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+)</td><td>(1?\d?\d)%</td><td>(1?\d?\d)%</td><td>(.+)</td><td>(.+)</td>
```

Comment: This is good, but the tags won't always be <td>, sometimes they will have attributes and say <td style=....>

Answer (score 1):

use **Character class**, like `<td[^>]*>` if `<td> or <td class="abc">`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(.+)(<[^>]+>){2}(1?\d?\d)%(<[^>]+>){2}(1?\d?\d)%(<[^>]+>){2}(.+)(<[^>]+>){2}(.+)<[^>]+>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce48k/).

EDIT: Although this will work for most of the time, if there is > character in one attribute of the tag, this regex won't work.

Comment: `>` is allowed in an attribute value.